# HTML <option> selected Attribute

Tags: html

I have a list of countries to be displayed in a dropdown box. Is there a way by which I can preselect 5(or more than one country) countries in the dropdown box ?

Comment: Have you tried `<select multiple` and  `<option selected` ?

Comment: I have tried '<'option selected, it works fine. I want 5 values to be preselected instead of one.

Comment: But have you added `selected` to each `option` that you want to be selected? You must add `multiple` to your `select` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

In the example below options volvo and opel are preselected.

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel" selected>Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```